# Bidirectional fetching in GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, relay, graphql, graphql-js

I have the following GraphQL schema:

```
interface Node {
  id: ID!
}

type User : Node {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  tasks: [Task]
}

type Task : Node {
  id: ID!
  day: Int!
  description: String!
}

type Viewer {
  users: [User]
}

type Query {
  viewer: Viewer
}
```

Basically, every user can have a list of tasks. The problem occurs when I need to fetch a list of all tasks to get a response like this:

```
tasks: [{
  day: 1,
  user: {
    name: "John"
  }
}, {
  day: 2,
  user: {
    name: "Jane"
  }
}]
```

How should I edit my schema to allow fetching like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to fetch a list of all tasks, add it as a property on the Viewer

```
type Viewer {
  users: [User]
  tasks: [Task]
}
```

and add `users` field to `Task`:

```
type Task : Node {
  id: ID!
  day: Int!
  description: String!
  users: [User]
}
```

With the updated schema, you can query for a list of all users as well as tasks:

```
{
  viewer {
    users {  // all users
      name
      tasks {  // user's tasks
        description
      }
    }
    tasks {  // all tasks
      day
      users {  // task's users
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you should be using pagination instead fetching all tasks (or users) at once. If you're planning to use your GraphQL server with Relay, define your users/tasks not as a List, but as a Connection with edges. See https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-connections.html#content